# Properties of exponents $e^{2.5-.5t}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How does $e^{2.5-.5t}$ = $e^{2.5}$($e^{-.5t}$)

I thought that $e^{2.5-.5t}$ = $e^{2.5/.5t}$.

does the variable t make my algebra incorrect?

Comment: The variable $t$ shouldn't disappear. Remember that $$x^a x^b = x^{a+b}.$$

Comment: spelling mistake

Comment: Note that $a^{-b}=\dfrac1{a^b}$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general $e^{a+b} = (e^a)(e^b)$, in your case a = 2.5 and b = -0.5t

Comment: b=-.5t it says.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

when taking the product of exponents, the answer is the sum of the exponents

for example $x^a \times x^b = x^{a+b}$

but $(x^a)^b = x^{ab}$